# Почему у групповых топонимов в родительном падеже обычно нулевое окончание (Мальдив, Альп, Курил)?

Tags: склонение, родительный-падеж

Согласно правилам (http://www.bibliotekar.ru/russkiy-yazik-2/122.htm), слова мужского рода во множественном числе в родительном падеже обычно имеют окончание -ов, а женского рода — обычно нулевое. Есть исключения для некоторых видов нарицательных слов (парных предметов, некоторых родов войск и национальностей, единиц измерения).

Между тем, чуть ли не все острова в родительном падеже имеют нулевое окончание: Мальдив, Канар, Мальвин, Курил (самое явное исключение — Гавайев). То же самое с горами: Карпат, Альп, Апеннин. То же с греческими городами: Афин, Фив, Сиракуз. Ещё Канн (вроде бы). Но: Сочей, Ессентук(ов).

Гипотеза про женский род не подходит: остров и город — мужского рода.

По какой причине мы выбираем нулевое окончание?

Comment: Похожая ситуация с существительными у которых нет формы единственного числа. С одной стороны: шахмат, макарон, ножниц, чернил. С другой: будней, яслей, очков.

Comment: +1 к @defaultlocale - действительно, я не уверен что дело вообще в топонимах

Comment: Мальдивы, Альпы и Курилы очевидно не имеют единственного числа.

Comment: "Остров" и "город" мужского рода, верно. А какого рода "Альпы", "Мальдивы" и "Курилы"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Old Russian used endings *-ъ, -ь* for nouns with historical *-o* stem in gen. pl.: *изъ Варягъ въ Грѣкы*, *изъ Грѣкъ по Днепру*, *святыхъ отецъ* etc. This means the modern zero-ending in words like *татар, армян, грузин* etc. is the "right", etymologically justified one.

The ending *-овъ* was initially used only for the nouns with historical *-u* stem. There were but a handful of those nouns: *сынъ, волъ, домъ* and several others. The *-в-* in oblique cases of those nouns is the remnant of the *-u* in the stem, and we can still see it now fossilized in plural forms of *сын* (*сыновья, сыновей*) etc., in the adjective *домой* (*< домови*, sg. dat. of *домъ*) and set phrases like *довлеет дневи злоба его*.

However, the ending *-овъ* began to spill to the *-o* stem paradigm as well and has since almost entirely supplanted the zero-ending, most probably to better differentiate between sg. nom and pl. gen.

As late as two hundred years ago *зуб, пуд, рог, месяц* were valid and widely used pl. gen. forms of respective nouns.

Zero-ending survived mostly in words which did not have to differentiate between sg. nom. and pl. gen.: all neuter words (which end in *-о* or *-е* in sg. nom.), most words in *-ин* (*татарин, болгарин* etc.), pair nouns (*сапог, чулок* etc., which are rarely used in sg. at all) etc.

However, this is only a rule of thumb, and you have to learn the declension for each noun by heart.

Comment: Не могли бы Вы добавить ссылки на источники данных?

Comment: Bravo! It really looks like the answer I asked for. Thanks.

Comment: @defaultlocale: Dmitry Shmelyov, *Избранные труды по русскому языку*, Moscow, 2002, p. 547

Answer (score 1):

Имена собственные (географические и астрономические): Афины, Карпаты, Балканы, Лубны, Сокольники, Плеяды, Близнецы относятся к существительным, употребляющимся только во множественном числе, называются pluralia tantum.
Они не имеют ни рода, ни склонения, потому что не имеют единственного числа, поэтому относить их к существительным мужского рода неправильно.
Существительные, употребляющиеся только во множественном числе, склоняются по образцу 1-го, 2-го и 3-го склонения, причем образец склонения определяется по родительному падежу. Никаких правил на этот счет не существует.

В Р. п. у существительных могут быть представлены окончания: нулевое, -ов, -ей.
I скл.: основное окончание — нулевое. 
II скл.: -ов/-ев, -ей, нулевое.