# Why do many military unit types have weird declension?

Tags: склонение, морфология, родительный-падеж

I mean plural genitive in "отряды драгун, улан, гусар, рейтар, кирасир, партизан, гренадир", but for some reason that doesn't apply to "отряды мушкетёров, юнкеров, сапёров и казаков".

1. Why does this apply to some unit types, but not the others? It's not "native vs non-native" or "modern vs historical".
2. Has it always been like that?

Comment: also **солдат**

Comment: please also see a reply by **Quassnoi** from a year ago https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/14099/7674

Answer (score 5):

Zero ending in Genitive plural could be a remnant or influence of both Church Slavonic, where both forms seem to be equivalent, and Old Russian, where it was characteristic of the words we now inflect differently.

> § 12 Существительныя на ъ, съ предшествующею согласною в, б, п, м, н, л, р, с, т, д, з, г, к, х, суть рода мужескаго, и склоняются слѣдующимъ образомъ:
>
> Множественнаго числа
>
> Родит. подобенъ именительному единственнаго ч. БИСЕРЪ, ВЛАСЪ, ВЪЛКЪ,
>   ВЛЪХВЪ, ВОСТОКЪ, ЗАПАДЪ и пр. -ОВЪ, рѣдко. Въ Остром. однажды
>   **греховъ**, въ Григ. Богосл. ХI в. **домовъ** и Супр. **из домовъ, оудовъ**.

<sup>*"Грамматика церковно-словенскаго языка, изложенная по дрѣвнейшимъ онаго письменным памятникамъ", А.Х. Востоков, стр. 15, 17*</sup>

> В твердом варианте склонения у существительных в родитель­ном  падеже 
>   встречается  окончание  **-ѡвъ**  и  нулевое  окончание. **Одно и  то
>   же  слово может  иметь  оба варианта окончания**:  `Сподоби  ѧ  видѣти  чада`**`чадѡвъ`**.  `Вѣнецъ  старыхъ  чада`**`чадъ`**  *[Притч.  17, 
>   6]*.  В существительных с нулевым окончанием для отличия от формы И.
>   ед.  используются  дополнительные  графические  средства, а именно: 
>   буквы **є, ѡ** и облеченное ударение.
>   В  мягком  варианте  склонения 
>   возможны  окончания  ־євъ, -Ей и нулевое окончание:  царЕй, 
>   іЕрЕєвъ,  **пѡль *(полей)***·

<sup>*"Церковнославянский язык", А.А. Плетнева, А.Г. Кравецкий, стр. 68*</sup>

> ***Существительные с основами* *-ŏ (столъ)*, *-jŏ (конь, поле)***
>
> **`Единственное  число`**
>             *-ŏ              *-jŏ
>         *М.р.*       *М.р.*   *Ср.р.*
>   И. дроугъ   конь  поле
>
> **`Множественное  число`**
>         *-ŏ             *-jŏ
>         *М.р.*       *М.р.*   *Ср.р.*
>   И. дроузи   кони  поля
>   Р. дроугъ   конь   поль
>
> ***Существительные с основой на согласный М.р.*** *** *-en***
>
> **`Единственное  число`**
>   И. камы *(камень)*
>
> **`Множественное  число`**
>   И. камене(ние)
>   Р. каменъ(ии)

<sup>*"[Древнерусский язык. Учебно методическое пособие](http://dialekt.vspu.ru/sites/dialekt.vspu.ru/files/metodichka.pdf)", Приложение 3 "Образцы склонения и спряжения", стр. 64-66*</sup>

И у Пушкина в "[Пророке](http://pesni.voskres.ru/poems/pushk02.htm)"

> И внял я неба содроганье,
>   И горний ангелов полет,
>   **И `гад` морских подводный ход.**
>   И дольней лозы прозябанье.

<sup>[A discussion some data sources was borrowed from](http://azangru.livejournal.com/294944.html)</sup>

---

And it also could be caused by interference of Genitive of feminine nouns, because in all other cases both masculine and feminine nouns inflect identically

***ед.ч.       мн.ч. И.п.    мн.ч. Р.п.***
***м.р.*** гусар       гусары          гусар
***ж.р.*** пара        пары             пар
***м.р.*** солдат    солдаты       солдат
***ж.р.*** палата     палаты        палат
***м.р.*** драгун     драгуны       драгун
***ж.р.*** лагуна      лагуны         лагун

Comment: Thanks, very interesting. Как давно в языке эти метания.

Answer (score 3):

One theory maintains that these exceptions from the regular pl.G. ending rule can most of the time be classified as collective nouns (not exactly the same phenomenon as well-known English collective nouns, by the way). They include:

- ethnic groups (*башкиры - башкир, грузины - грузин*)
- military formations
- fruit and veg (*баклажаны - баклажан, помидоры - помидор*)
- units of measurment (*граммы - грамм, амперы - ампер*)
- ...and there may be more

Unfortunately I could not find any articles that would clearly explain quite why that is the case. However, where saying smth like *полк солдат, эскадрон гусар, грядка помидор* is possible, this zero ending may turn out to be the correct pl.G. form.

Comment: Are you sure about помидор and баклажан? I've been taught they should always take -ов in proper Russian.

Comment: @Alexey, "200 грамм" too may sound colloquial compared to the more formal "200 граммов". Given this whole exception is an ostensibly fading one, I am not surprised you hear *баклажан* and *помидор* as "вульг-простореч".

Answer (score 3):

Actually de-facto, form like `гусаров, партизанов, солдатов` are perfectly legal but have slightly different meaning. Here's a [quote](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%80):

> Существительное, одушевлённое, мужской род, 2-е склонение (тип
>   склонения 1a((2)) по классификации А. А. Зализняка); в род. п. мн. ч.
>   допускается форма гуса́р (преимущ. при собир. знач.) и гуса́ров
>   (преимущ. при обознач. отдельных лиц).

Here's another [quote](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2), more general:

> Названия людей по национальности и по принадлежности к воинским
>   соединениям, преимущественно употребляющиеся в формах множественного
>   числа в собирательном значении: мадьяры - мадьяр, туркмены - туркмен,
>   гардемарины - гардемаринов и гардемарин, партизаны - партизан, солдаты
>   - солдат; сюда же относится форма р. п. мн. ч. человек.

And it's indeed the case. For instance, when one talk about `партизаны` as a whole they most likely would say `партизан`, when one will talk about some specific group, he/she most likely will say `партизанов`.

For instance:

- В этом лесу много партизан.
- Пары партизанов хватит чтобы устроить тут диверсию.

So, being back to your question, it's just happened that military ranks by their nature denote some general group of people, that's why.

Comment: same for ethnic groups, if a finite number of people is meant then -oв ending would be more appropriate to denote males

Comment: yep, same for ethnic group - exactly like it's  told in the quote provided ;)

Comment: in the [quotation](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/66-plural) i see reference to naming infinite number of people with zero ending, but not to their finite number with ending -ов

Comment: "преимущественно употребляющиеся в формах множественного числа в **собирательном значении**" which means zero ending, not -ов ending, like the examples which follow show... to be clear i wasn't correcting yourself, i just added a missing piece of info for future readers

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка that's a good point indeed